# Sharing the x-axis

Tags: r, data-visualization

Consider the output of the following R code:

```
par( mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1 )
boxplot( t( matrix( rnorm( 100 ), nrow=10 )), xlab="Var1", ylab="Var2")
par( new=T )
plot( 1:10, runif(10,min=-2, max=3), xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab='', ylab='', type='b', col='blue', pch=15 )
axis(4)
mtext("Var3", side=4, line=3 )
```

The blue points are not aligned with the x-axis. I would like to get both plots to share the x-axis correctly. I've tried using the `at` argument to `boxplot` but that gives me weird output.

Thanks in advance!

PK
^_^

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `lines` ?

```
par( mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1 )
boxplot( t( matrix( rnorm( 100 ), nrow=10 )), xlab="Var1", ylab="Var2")
lines( 1:10, runif(10,min=-2, max=3), type='b', col='blue', pch=15 )
axis(4)
mtext("Var3", side=4, line=3 )
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer.  Making multiple plot calls is a rookie mistake we all make.  With the base 'plot' function (and most other plotting functions), you only call the plot once and then add other forms of notation to that plotting space.  I would note that you don't need all of those additional arguments for the 'lines' function.  You can write it as just `lines( 1:10, runif(10,min=-2, max=3), type='b', col='blue', pch=15 )`, since it's a geometry call and not a plot call.

Comment: @Dinre of course, you're right, I was too lazy and just replaced `plot` with `lines`. Edited, and thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @polarise If it solved your problem, you can check the green mark. This will inform other users and display the question as answered.

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't work for

    par( mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1 )
    boxplot( t( matrix( rnorm( 100 ), nrow=10 )), xlab="Var1", ylab="Var2")
    lines( 1:10, runif(10,min=-10, max=30), type='b', col='blue', pch=15, yaxt='n' )
    axis(4)
    mtext("Var3", side=4, line=3 )

I would like to have two separate scales on each y-axis.

Comment: @juba This seems to work for the special case presented. Could you please take a second look? Thanks.

Comment: @polarise Yes, if you use `lines`, you won't have two separate scales, as the lines are plotted using the scale of your original `y` axis.

Comment: @polarise To keep them in separate scales, use your original syntax in the question, but in the plot statement, add "xlim=c(0.5, 10.5)," and then the two plot will align. In boxplot the x axis is augmented 0.5 unit each side to accommodate the box width, if you just overlay without adding that back, the new line plot will be off.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Thanks. What should be the solution in general? This was just an example I cooked up but my data has different limits and I don't want to twiddle values.

Comment: @polarise Name the min(x) and max(x) as their objects, then add "xlim=c(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5)" into the line plot statement. I don't know if that is considered as twiddling, but it's as automatic as I can make it.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I'm afraid it doesn't generalise. Thanks though. I'll figure something out.